# mutating trigger table when update one table from another

Tags: oracle, plsql

Table is mutating when run this code please help me where i go wrong? Thank you

```
`CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_tri
after update of country ON test_1
for each row
when (new.country = 'SomeCountry')
begin
update test_2 set column_1 = 'Something'
where test_1.id = (Select id from test_1,test_2 where test_1.id=test_2.id) `
```

Comment: Have you tried searching? The are many questions about similar issues

Comment: yas,but 'when (new.country = 'SomeCountry')' make all quary diferent

Comment: Are there any triggers on test_2? Are they possibly updating test_1?

Comment: You have not shown the complete code which will tell us what were you trying to do in the update statement. This Trigger will not compile.

Comment: When working with Oracle DB, best practice with triggers is... don't use them (when you want to implement business logic). Create specific package with DML procedures,use them and be free of trigger headache's.

Comment: i must use trigger it work without 'when(new......)' and 'for each row' but this take a lot of resources!

Answer (score 1):

An attempt to clarify, more than a real answer; if I understand well you need, your trigger is overcomplicated and you may simply need:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_tri
    AFTER UPDATE OF country
    ON test_1
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN(new.country = 'SomeCountry')
BEGIN
    UPDATE test_2
       SET column_1    = 'Something'
     WHERE test_2.id = :new.id;
END;
```

For example:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from test_2;

        ID COLUMN_1
---------- ----------------
         1 xx

SQL> update test_1
  2  set country = 'SomeCountry';

1 row updated.

SQL> select *
  2  from test_2;

        ID COLUMN_1
---------- ----------------
         1 Something
```

This works in a structure made like this, without triggers:

```
create table test_1 (id number, country varchar2(100));
create table test_2 (id number, column_1 varchar2(100));
```

If you have different tables, other triggers and so on, please post them.

Comment: No matter because i update different column from test_1 column id  will be new?

Comment: I can't get the point. Please post your complete table structure, some sample data, the update query you do and the result you expect from this. This will help people to understand the issue

Comment: Thank you Aleksej i try this code and i send you feedback

Comment: Works excelent, this solve problem with mutating table "WHERE test_2.id = :new.id;"

Answer (score 0):

A mutation table is defined as a table that is changing. But in dealing with triggers, it is a table that has the possibility of changing.

If you really need to use the table test_1 on your SQL, you must to add the hint pragma autonomous_transaction

Like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_tri
after update of country ON test_1
for each row
when (new.country = 'SomeCountry')
 pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
update test_2 set column_1 = 'Something'
where test_1.id = (Select id from test_1,test_2 where test_1.id=test_2.id)
```